# What is dominantimages and why is Edge asking ieonline.microsoft.com for it?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I have a local Apache webserver set up and I was accessing my site via Microsoft Edge.  I have the hosts file and Apache's VirtualHosts set up to let me access `http://app.local.tld` (this points to `127.0.0.1`).

In Edge's developer tools, I saw the following request when loading my page:

```
http://ieonline.microsoft.com/suggestions/ie/dominantimages?qry=url:http://app.local.tld
```

This returned an XML response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<dominantimageresponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Search/2013/dominantimage">
    <url>http://app.local.tld</url>
    <imagedata></imagedata>
</dominantimageresponse>
```

What is this request/response for?  What is Edge asking Microsoft for about the URL I am going to?  `http://app.local.tld` only exists on my machine, so it's obviously not useful to them.

**EDIT**: I also see a request to

```
https://t.urs.microsoft.com/urstelemetry.asmx?MSTel-Client-Key=SOME_KEY
```

Some searching revealed this URL may be for "SmartScreen", so I think this is unrelated.

**EDIT 2**: Might `dominantimages` be for Edge's "live tile" or "top sites"?  When I change the URL in the query to `http://microsoft.com`, I get some more data back.

```
http://ieonline.microsoft.com/suggestions/ie/dominantimages?qry=url:http://microsoft.com
```

This gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<dominantimageresponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Search/2013/dominantimage">
    <url>http://microsoft.com</url>
    <imagedata>{},{0|0|2.09999990463|http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f5/Microsoft_logo_and_wordmark.svg/220px-Microsoft_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png^0|0|0.899999976158|http://c.s-microsoft.com/en-us/CMSImages/BTS_StoreYellow_0715_768x768_EN_US.jpg?version=0746beba-3539-1599-1ea6-ae1ce691fa15^0|0|0.600000023842|https://assets.onestore.ms/cdnfiles/onestorerolling-1508-24008/shell/v2_5/images/logo/microsoft.png}</imagedata>
</dominantimageresponse>
```

Comment: Your guess is most likely the answer - it probably asks the MS server for an image representation of the site for used in the live tile or top sites page.

Comment: @Chin: Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: It's kinda funny that Microsoft uses Wikipedia for its own logo.

Comment: The fact that it uses a Wikipedia image makes it sound to me like it's more likely related to Cortana/Bing Search.  Also notice the XML schema reference contains the word "Search" and that the URL contains the word "suggestions."

Comment: @JosiahKeller: That's a good observation!  That makes sense.

Comment: I found some more info here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-preview-privacy-statement#ie=ie-11 `In order to get the dominant images for the page, Internet Explorer will send the webpage address, along with some standard PC information to Microsoft`

Comment: Oh, well if it also applies to IE then maybe it's not about Cortana since IE doesn't integrate Cortana like Edge does.

Comment: That privacy statement does mention pinning.  So that's probably what it is, then.